# How to write dynamic variable name in Vue's class binding ternary operator?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have some problems of writing a dynamically generated variable name in Vue's class binding ternary operator. This is my code:

```
<div v-bind:class="[VARIABLE HERE? 'partition-active': '', 'partition']" v-for="(item,index) in partitionContent" v-bind:key="index"></div>
```

So in the ternary operator, I would like to write flag0 or flag1 or flag2 or such things according to the v-for's index.

But if I use string's concatenation like 'flag' + index， it would simply be a string as always, and the class would always be 'partition-active'. How should I write REAL variables here? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're over thinking this, to be honest with you. Why not set the active index as a data variable, then you can just do:

```
:class="[VARIABLE HERE === `flag-${index}` ? 'partition-active': '', 'partition']
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have just solved this via another way. Adding another attribute whose value is a boolean type in the object array in Vue's data. Then directly use item.newAttribute in the ternary operator. Hope this can help anyone if ever possible